# Convert json date format from one timezone to another in php

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

While using google api for feed, I get blog post's creation time in format - `2015-04-11T06:33:00.001-07:00` which is datestamp for another timezone. I want to convert datestamp to IST timezone (eg. `2015-04-12T09:51:00.001+05:30`) with php. How do I do that?

In another question what all I could find is convert `2015-04-12T09:51:00.001` to another format, that's it. I am unable to convert it to mentioned format.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert one date format into another in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php)

Comment: @Huey - how's this possible duplicate when there's no mention of changine timezone that too in json date format there.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be easily accomplished with DateTime:

```php
$dt = new DateTime('2015-04-11T06:33:00.001-07:00');
$dt->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Colombo'));
echo $dt->format('c');
```

<kbd>**[demo](https://eval.in/312323)**</kbd>

Comment: woah.. that did in seconds... i was thinking of first getting timezone of date and then cast to this. But your solution help avoid that step and save time.  thanks man.

Comment: No need for that, DateTime knows how to deal with timezones, and a lot more :) [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) is the list of timezones, if you need it...

Comment: was just on that link changing time zone from Asia/Colombo to Asia/Kolkata.